# Browser extension/add-on to copy title to clipboard

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, clipboard, url, hyperlink

Is there a Firefox add-on or Chrome extension to copy the current page title + url as a link, so that I could insert it into Google/MS Office/Libre Office docs?

It's generally convenient to have a (section in a) document with links related to the task/subject having a clear name. And it would be nice to have the action automated.

Comment: On [softwarerecs.se]: [Chrome extension to copy the link & URL of the page as a single line Rich Text Format hyperlink to the clipboard](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14897/60) ··· [Firefox extension to copy the title and URL of the page to the clipboard](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3772/60)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the [Tabcopy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcopy/micdllihgoppmejpecmkilggmaagfdmb) and works fine.

This extension adds an icon to the address bar to quickly copy tab titles and URLs to the clipboard.

It also allows for customization of the output format with a variety of options, including Markdown, BB code, JSON, HTML, and custom templates.

Supports three functions:

```
1. Use single click to copy selected tabs in the current window.
2. Use double click to copy all tabs in the current window.
3. Use triple clicks to copy all tabs (tabs open in separate windows).
```

There is also an alternative for the same, [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url-%20-title/dgagjmdgbakclelfacghmmbadkdegjjh?hl=en).

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. Provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Much better ... ;)

Comment: The only problem with it is that it's not clear how to insert this as a link into Google Doc. You cannot insert HTML there.

Comment: You can do it, I just pasted this in sheet and it detected it as a link. For plain docs, just use the title as text and then use the link option which will ask you for link, just paste the link there.